# How to connect a four route MOSFET to multiple power sources?

Tags: arduino, power, mosfet, led-strip

I have this four channel MOSFET switch:
[image: MOSFET Switch]

I have connected one RGB LED-strip to this, and controlling it from an Arduino, and this works great.

The problem is that I need to control four of these LED-strips, and they each need 12V. So I wan't to remove the 12V from connection to the board, and connect it directly to the LED's, and then control the RGB values on the LEDs from the board (the will all be controlled identically, so the are connected together). How would I go about doing this?

When I connected one LED-strip, I did what is described in this tutorial: http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Brick-4ChannelPowerFetSwitch

But I need to wire it more like this illustration, where the power is directly connected to the LED, so that I can control multiple LED-strips at once:
[image: LED wiring]

Comment: You mentioned "arduino", then then I see a wiring diagram instead of a schematic.  This doesn't sound like a electronics question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the device schematic on your linked page, I see that the power + terminal is directly connected to each output + terminal, as well as the internal circuitry. Therefore, you are free to connect the plus side of each load (LED strip) to either the output + terminal or the plus side of the 12V power source.

Just make sure that you do connect the power terminals of your MOSFET board, even if you don't use the plus output terminals.

Edit: the OP clarified that he wants to use a separate 12V source for each LED strip. This is fine. You can do the following:

- Connect all negative leads (from power supplies) together and to the MOSFET power input connector.
- Connect each positive lead to one LED strip. Chose one of the power supplies and also connect its positive lead to the MOSFET board power connector.
- Each LED strip negative lead goes to the negative side of the corresponding board output.
- **Do not connect all of the positive leads together!**

Each power supply will power one LED strip. One of the supplies will also power the board (very little power draw).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is that each LED-strip needs 12V, but I guess i can't connect all for 12V adapterts to the board, because then the LED-strip will be overloaded. So I need that the four 12V adapterts are seperatly connected to each LED-strip!